# How to select a Picker with MenuPickerStyle outside of the label text

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a simple menu picker that I have placed within a rounded rectangle border and chevron image. I'd like for users to be able to tap anywhere within this rectangle to activate the showing of the picker options but no matter what it only seems to be selectable within the actual text (see image with highlighted blue border). Is there any way to achieve this without scaling the text?

I've tried adding padding and scaling modifiers with no such luck.

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        HStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .frame(height: 40)
            Image(uiImage: Icon.chevronDown.image())
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 8))
        }
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1)
        )
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 16))
        Picker(selectedOption, selection: $selectedOption) {
            ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                Text(option)
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
    }
}
```

[image: picker menu]

How can I make the white area between the rounded black border and the blue text selectable to active the menu picker options the same way as tapping on the actual blue text?

Comment: Tricky part here is that giving `Picker` an explicit `label` seems to be ignored if the view is not something like `Text`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Picker(selection:label:content:)`, which takes a View as the `label:` argument. Put everything you want as the tappable view *inside* the `label:` argument, like so:

```
var body: some View {
        
    Picker(selection: $selectedOption, label:
            
            HStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.systemBackground))
                    .frame(height: 40)
                Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 8))
            }
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1)
            )
            .overlay(
                Text("Picker Option \(selectedOption)")
            )
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 16))
    ) {
        ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
            Text("Picker Option \(option)")
        }
    }
    .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
}
```

**Update:** The above code doesn’t work in Xcode 13 beta 5. Hopefully it’s a bug, but if not, here is a workaround: put the Picker in a Menu!

```
var body: some View {
        
    Menu {
        Picker("picker", selection: $selectedOption) {
            ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                Text("Picker Option \(option)")
            }
        }
        .labelsHidden()
        .pickerStyle(InlinePickerStyle())

    } label: {

        HStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(.systemBackground))
                .frame(height: 40)
            Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 8))
        }
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1)
        )
        .overlay(
            Text("Picker Option \(selectedOption)")
        )
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 16))
    }
}
```

Comment: This example doesn't work for me, all the other views like the rounded rectangle and image are just ignored or not visible. All I can see is the blue `Text` for the picker option…

Comment: @George Are you using Xcode 13 beta? This works in Xcode 12.5, but I just opened Xcode 13 beta and I see the same thing you described…

Comment: Yep, currently Xcode 13b5 in iOS 15 simulator. I really hope they haven't removed this...

Comment: Hopefully it’s a bug, but if not I’ve edited my answer with a workaround.

Comment: The workaround looks as I wanted, but the selection is not working for me. Neither the selection is shown, nor there is a checkmark if you again open the menu after selected one.